# Issues with Requests dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog

I'm a little confused using FB request dialog (sendRequestToManyRecipients).
Following the example found on FB developers' section, I succeed displaying the popup but I'm having a problem with the request received by the friend. Indeed the link he receive shows a 404 error page.
I'd just like to know how I can add the parameter with the landing page I want the user be redirected on.
If only it's possible...

Here is the code I use:

```
<script>

FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxxxxx',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth  : true
});

function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        app_id: 'xxxxxx',
        message: 'My message',
        }, requestCallback);
    }

function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
}

</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the request landing page for requests, **BUT** you know where he'll be sent :

> User Response
>
> If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will be sent to the
>   canvas URL of the application that sent the request. This URL will
>   contain an additional parameter, request_ids, which is a comma
>   delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon:
>
> `https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]`

( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ )

It's up to you to look if there's a request_ids parameter when a user come to your application, to check if the request is valid, and to redirect him to whatever you want (a different page, processing request, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had see this point, but I didn't know I could use it to redirect the user. I am not very comfortable with the facebook sdk. I'll try to make something with that.

Comment: After many tries, I finaly ask "Social Server" the service I use to get my apps secured (https) and the problem comes from the interception by their servers so the graph api don't give results. I'll now try with another https service.

Comment: At least you're going further ! Let me know if you still have issues with that !